# App freezes on custom Android Kitkat 4.4 with failed de-queue buffer error

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, posiflex

Am running my app on a [Posiflex machine](http://posiflex.com/en-global/product/index/pos-terminal/JIVA-XT/JIVA_XT-2614Q) which runs Android 4.4. My home page is a webview(which will use Chromium 30). Sometimes my app freezes and the logcat shows the following error

```
DequeueBufferWrapper: Failed to de-queue buffer

Native window is invalid
```

After the above error theres also a stack trace with:

```
ViewRootImpl: Could not lock surface
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 00:07:48.092 12167-12167/in.zeta.android.pos.debug E/Surface: dequeueBuffer failed (Invalid argument)
01-29 00:07:48.092 12167-12167/in.zeta.android.pos.debug 

E/ViewRootImpl: Could not lock surface
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:246)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am simply using this device and have no control on how the `Surface` or custom views have been implemented. Is there any workaround for this issue. My app freezes after such an error.

Answer (score 0):

After observing several cases of the same error, I have found that the error may happen only on using a `Webview` in android Kitkat (Android 4.4),the fast solution if you are sure you will only run the app on Kitkat is by turning off hardware acceleration:

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

but if you support different versions (other devices) then:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){ 
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  }
```

Comment: I have already tried out this solution. Even after disabling hardware acceleration for the webview, i have seen crashes happening with this stack trace.